# How to set PhpStorm scss watcher if css and scss are separate sibling folders in static

Tags: sass, phpstorm, siblings

I'm using PhpStorm. I've installed Ruby and npm Sass. I want to set scss watcher like below:

input FileDir is

```
"c:\test\static\scss\(can be file  folder\file or folder\folder\file)"
```

output FileDir is

```
"c:\test\static\css\(can be file or folder\file or folder\folder\file)"
```

So I just want to simply change `\scss\` to `\csss\` of FileDir.

#### This is what I'm doing for setting in PhpStorm.

Arguments:

```
 --update $FileName$:$ContentRoot$\static\scss\$FileDirPathFromParent(scss)$$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

Ouput paths to refresh:

```
1.(tried)
 $ContentRoot$\static\css\$FileDirPathFromParent(css)$$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

2.(tried)
$ContentRoot$\static\css\$FileDirPathFromParent(scss)$$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

It makes a css file under `c:\test\static\scss\` folder
not `c:\test\static\css\` folder.

What should I do?

Comment: Why not use a bundler like gulp or webpack which can be used outside of phpstorm as well?

Comment: So .. what tool do you use to compile your SCSS code? Ruby Sass or the one installed via npm (Dart Sass `npm install -g sass`)? I'm using **node-sass** (`npm install -g node-sass`) and Arguments is as simple as `--output-style expanded --output $FileParentDir(scss)$\css\$FileDirPathFromParent(scss)$ $FileName$`

Comment: Just to be clear: this will specify the folder (so add file name bit if it's required in your tool): `$FileParentDir(scss)$\css\$FileDirPathFromParent(scss)$`

Comment: I used " -g node sass".
Still, your code didn't work for me.
Thank you for your comment, though. Have a good day. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest changing arguments as follows:

**Arguments:** `$FileName$:$ProjectFileDir$\static\css\$FileDirPathFromParent(scss)$$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`

**Ouput paths to refresh:** `$ProjectFileDir$/static/css/$FileDirPathFromParent(scss)$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$ProjectFileDir$/static/css/$FileDirPathFromParent(scss)$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map`

[image]

Comment: It works finally!!!!!
Thank you so much for your exellent code!
You saved me! 
Have a nice day!!!

Comment: Glad to help! please can you accept my answer then?:)

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance. ^^; It's  first time that I used it. Thanks let me know.